# Azure SQL get data from another non-Azure sql server using Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We have two **SQL Server Database** (EG: DB1 & DB2) that are hosted in NON-Azure environment (dedicated server). We are planning to migrate DB1 to Azure SQL.

Is there way the Azure SQL DB1 can talk to non-azure DB2 using Linked Server approach? I want to query in my Azure SQL (DB1) and get the data of DB2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can certainly do that.

This atricle explains all the details that you need to do to accomplish that:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3630/connect-an-azure-sql-database-to-an-onpremises-sql-server/

Note that your SQL Azure instance needs to be in "Standard" service tier to be able to do that.

If you want to add your SQL Azure server as a linked server to your on-prem SQL you can use ODBC connection.
Bellow MSDN article will help you with that:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2011/03/07/linked-servers-to-sql-azure/

Comment: This one connects a Azure SQL to an on premise db. I need the exact opposite, connect on premise to Azure SQL.

Comment: @SureshKumarNarayanasamy you can use ODBC for adding SQL Azure as linked server. look at this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2011/03/07/linked-servers-to-sql-azure/

Comment: Since I wrote that article, I am up ticking the response.  Linked servers have to be created on virtual machine or physical machine or Infrastructure as a service (IAAS).  This is because they are built on top of OLEDB.  Azure SQL database is a platform as a service (PAAS) offering.  Therefore, you can only pull/pull data from the first configuration.  The later does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are trying to connect your Azure-db (DB1) from an on-premise db (DB2). From on-premises SQL Server, you can use linked servers and 4-part names to point to a database in Azure SQL DB using a datasource which would look like this - 
`[YourAzureServerName@database.windows.net].[YourDatabaseName].[YourSchemaName].[YourTableName]`

For more details please check this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2011/03/07/linked-servers-to-sql-azure/).